# GAE/J Datastore Presistent Jdo deleting Issue

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo, datanucleus

Currently My Parent Class Looks like this,

```
public class UserVotesJDO {

@PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    @Persistent
    private String mediaId;

    @Persistent(dependent="true")
    private LikesJDO likes;

    @Persistent(dependent="true")
    private HatesJDO hates;
```

// with getters and setters and other variables
    }

and my Child class hatesJDO looks like

```
@PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true")
public class HatesJDO {

@PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

@Persistent
private int count;

private List<UserJDO> hatesUsersList;
}
```

where UserJDO is Another Child Class which looks like below,

```
@PersistenceCapable(detachable="true")
public class UserJDO {

@PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

@Persistent
private String userId;

@Persistent
private String userName;

@Persistent
private String fullName;

@Persistent
private String userEmail;
}
```

my logic is when i delete UserVote i no longer need those dependent child hates and likes, and its UserJDO
so **when i try to delete UserVotesJDO Object, am getting warning in console as below**

```
Delete of com.shoewars.jdo.UserVotesJDO@8b4163 needs delete of related object at com.shoewars.jdo.ShoeWarsUserVotesJDO.hates but cannot delete it direct since FK is here
```

i dint get this point foreign key is current referred or used .....

Can anyone help me fix this issue!

Since this was my first post, i dont know how to post properly, anyways, i will explain what i'm trying to do

i have an JDO which stores an Image ID  and, people info of those who likes this image and also those who hates this images

for this purpose i have create two more JDO likesJDO and HatesJDO, to store the list separately.

so, when i save information about vote in jdo, following things happens

1. get user information and store it accordingly in UsersList of either hates or likes
2. add these to UserVote JDO along with image id
3. finally persist it

now, my problem is, when i delete UserVote JDO, i want those record in hatesJDO and likesJDO to be deleted that why i have added

```
@Persistent(dependent="true")
private LikesJDO likes;

@Persistent(dependent="true")
private HatesJDO hates;
```

these lines

but now, am getting exception while doing this

the stacktrace will be like :

```
com.uservote.service.UserVotesOperations updateUserVoteForMedia: Cannot read fields from a deleted object
javax.jdo.JDOUserException: Cannot read fields from a deleted object
FailedObject:com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key:UserVotesJDO(80003)/LikesJDO(1)/UserJDO(2001)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.state.PersistentDeleted.transitionReadField(PersistentDeleted.java:116)
    at org.datanucleus.state.AbstractStateManager.transitionReadField(AbstractStateManager.java:838)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.isLoaded(JDOStateManager.java:1699)
    at com.uservotes.jdo.UserJDO.jdoGetuserId(UserJDO.java)
    at com.uservotes.jdo.UserJDO.getUserDTO(UserJDO.java:157)
    at com.uservotes.service.InstagramApiService.convertToUserDtoList(InstagramApiService.java:555)
    at com.uservotes.jdo.LikesJDO.getLikesDTO(LikesJDO.java:95)
    at com.uservotes.jdo.uservotesUserVotesJDO.getuservotesUserVotesDTO(uservotesUserVotesJDO.java:109)
    at com.uservotes.service.UserVotesOperations.updateUserVoteForMedia(UserVotesOperations.java:242)
    at com.uservotes.service.UserVotesOperations.updateUserVoteForMediaList(UserVotesOperations.java:162)
    at com.uservotes.controller.UserVotesController.hanldeUpdateUserVotesRequest(UserVotesController.java:111)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_$1.run(Method_.java:165)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_.privilegedInvoke(Method_.java:163)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_.invoke_(Method_.java:124)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_.invoke(Method_.java:43)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:102)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:266)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:447)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:454)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:461)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:703)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:338)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:330)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:458)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Comment: Posting the stack trace with any exception would be essential, and the version of the software being used, and the persistence code to generate the objects in the first place, and the persistence code to delete the object(s). That would be way better than posting duplicate issues http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042628/how-to-delete-dependent-child-class-when-deleting-parent-jdo-in-google-app-engin

Comment: Since i dint get any response for long time (probably 1 week), i thought to edit the title to be more relevant , but forgot to delete the old one. thanks

Comment: no response likely means people were on holiday. besides I told you above that there are very basic things missing from your post, so doubt you'll get some deep insight without providing it. And then you can just look at the log which tells you all that is happening

Comment: i Mentioned my problem , but still here more clear explaination, i have an class with two dependent child class , so when i am deleting my parent , i get this warning in google app engine console, **Delete of com.uservotes.jdo.UserVotesJDO@efae3b needs delete of related object at com.uservotes.jdo.UserVotesJDO.likes but cannot delete it direct since FK is here**

Answer (score 0):

Seems like its something related to Lazy Load. Try accessing likes & hates (by getLikes() & getHates()) just before delete.